Need Help Increasing PWM Frequency from 800 Hz to 8000+ Hz for DC Motor Speed Control
I'm currently developing a speed control system for a powerful 12V DC motor that pulls a heavy load. To enhance system efficiency, I need to raise the PWM frequency from the 800 Hz (PLC upper limit) provided by the PLC to at least 8000 Hz.
One alternative is using a large low-pass filter, but this would require an inductor at least 2 mH capable of managing 70-80 amps, which is either unobtainable or prohibitively expensive.
I have minimal experience with ICs and MCUs but I am willing to explore these options. I've heard about PLLs and other frequency-altering devices but am unsure where to start looking for these components, especially concerning specific product names or categories in electronics suppliers like TME.eu.
Are there any ICs or simple methods with simple circuits that could serve as a straightforward "plug and play" solution to achieve this frequency increase? (I don't need the greatest accuracy or resolution - 7-bit resolution is good enough, duty cycle is controlled by PID that is regulated by motor RPM)
Any guidance on ICs or setups that could help me accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Where’s the existing 800Hz coming from, and why would increasing to 8kHz be a problem?

@Frog: My main control unit is an Intercontrol PLC, programmable via Codesys. It supports PWM outputs ranging from 100 Hz to 800 Hz. The output voltage closely matches the input, typically around 12-13 volts in my setup.

Any safety features of the PLC void be voided for the outputs. It would probably be easier to do analog voltage to pwm. Then you have a 8kHz triangle oscillator and a comparator for each pwm channel.

@Kartman - My plc doesn't have an analogue output. I have thought of using LTC2645 and LTC6992-1 as someone else described in their solution. I can't believe that a concept as simple as that doesn't have dedicated ICs. (I guess there is a good reason for it)

You can add a RC filter to your pwm output to obtain an analog voltage.

I'd use a microcontroller. You can use a capture/compare peripheral to measure the duty cycle from the PLC, and a PWM peripheral to output the higher frequency.  You might want to go to 20 kHz in order to avoid audible noise.

I thought efficiency was better with lower frequency PWM: less switching == lower switching losses...

@dandavis - well, it depends. If you imagine a PWM with a duty cycle of 20% and a frequency of 1 Hz, then there is not enough inertia to keep it moving smoothly - hence the losses. My motor grinds through thick substance so it can stall easily and it has quite low inductance, so it does not have enough inertia to keep current stable (aka torque). So it leaves me with two options: either increase the frequency or add an extra inductance (over 300$).

if there's not enough power to prevent the motor from stalling out, I would think it unlikely that more frequent but smaller/shorter kicks giving the same power would help much. A pizza doesn't get more filling by cutting it into smaller pieces. That said, I 2nd the MCU; highpass the PLC PWM into an analog voltage, then set the MCU's duty cycle by (read_v/12)*max_duty and feed the output into wherever the PLC's output went. Use an optocoupler if needed.

@dandavis Thanks, I will first do further testing with 800 Hz and see how it goes (I have changed the electric circuit design from the last setup). To give some back information on why I posted this question - I did an LTspice model and these are the results for motor current (DC=10%) 800 Hz vs 8000 Hz: https://imgur.com/a/WnicQdJ

you can see the blue trace actually delivers lower average power, which makes sense since it has 10x the switching losses, dead zones, and rise times. That said, i don't know how good you can simulate a real-world motor loading...
